# Bash, running a command as an argument with arguments, and the continuing the original command

Tags: bash

Sorry for the very confusing title, but here's what im trying to do:

```
 TORQUEBOX_START="$TORQUEBOX_HOME/jboss/bin/standalone.sh"
 TORQUEBOX_START_ARGS="--server-config=standalone-ha.xml"

start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --chuid  $DAEMONUSER  \
  --exec "${TORQUEBOX_START}" -- ${TORQUEBOX_START_ARGS}  --pidfile $PIDFILE --make-pidfile -- -c $TORQUEBOX_SERVER >> $LOGFILE 2>&1 &
```

I need to run the TORQUEBOX_START with its arguments in the --exec argument. I tried using -- to pass the args to it. But from there I dont really know how i can pop back to passing args to the original command. The `--pidfile` for example needs to pass to `start-stop-daemon`. Is there a way to do this or a way you can suggest?

Comment: How about using a 3rd string to concatenate the first 2?  Not pretty but should work.

CMD="$TORQUEBOX_START $TORQUEBOX_START_ARGS"

Comment: I was initially passing it as a single string, even just hardcoding the torquebox_home path. It doesnt work quite right in single quotes, and in double quotes the --server-config argument is interpreted as an argument for start-stop-daemon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
TORQUEBOX_START="$TORQUEBOX_HOME/jboss/bin/standalone.sh"
TORQUEBOX_START_ARGS="--server-config=standalone-ha.xml"

start-stop-daemon \
  --start --quiet \
  --chuid $DAEMONUSER \
  --exec $TORQUEBOX_START \
  --pidfile $PIDFILE --make-pidfile \
  -- -c $TORQUEBOX_SERVER ${TORQUEBOX_START_ARGS} \
  >> $LOGFILE 2>&1
```